# How to use local file as thumbnail in Discord JDA embedded message?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I want to set the Thumbnail of an Embed to an Image which is local on my pc.

Is this possible?

```
EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
builder.setThumbnail("1.png"); //relative path
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861265/discord-jda-using-a-local-image-in-an-embed) (instead of using embed.setImage you obviously use embed.setThumbnail)

Answer (score 0):

```
 * Sets the Thumbnail of the embed.
 * MessageChannel channel; // = reference of a MessageChannel
 * EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
 * InputStream file = new URL("https://http.cat/500").openStream();
 * embed.setThumbnail("attachment://cat.png") // we specify this in sendFile as "cat.png"
 *      .setDescription("This is a cute cat :3");
 * channel.sendFiles(FileUpload.fromData(file, "cat.png")).setEmbeds(embed.build()).queue();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).